# How to get the object that stored in local storage

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.8

I want to get profile_id from my object stored in local storage but it shows error it says

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" ("
</div>
</div>[ERROR ->]"): a@24:6
```

my Component:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Id } from './id';

@Injectable()
export class GetId {
    str = localStorage.getItem('social_id');
    loc = JSON.parse(this.str);
    id = this.loc.profile_id;

    private _productUrl = 'http://localhost/a2server/index.php/requests/getrequestnotification/' + this.id;

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getId(): Observable<Id[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._productUrl).map((response: Response) => {
            console.log(response);
            return <Id[]> response.json();
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest help please..........

Comment: Show how you use this service and template.

Comment: Looks like redundant `</div>`. Please provide the code of your template so we can confirm that.